# How to use dotenv-webpack with angular and nx

Tags: angular, webpack, environment-variables, nx.dev

I want to configure a `.env` file in my app so I can define my env variables from codebuild.
I have an angular application in a nx workspace.
I'm overriding my webpack to configure `dotenv-webpack`, but I'm getting this error when I try to build my app using `nx build --prod`

```
A value for 'process' cannot be determined statically, as it is an external declaration.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my webpack:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = (config, context) => {
    return {
        ...config,
        plugins: [
            ...config.plugins,
            new Dotenv({
                systemvars: true,
            }),
        ],
    };
};
```

Here is the app config on angular.json:

```
"myapp": {
    "projectType": "application",
    "root": "apps/myapp",
    "sourceRoot": "apps/myapp/src",
    "architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
            "options": {
                "customWebpackConfig": {
                    "path": "apps/myapp/webpackConfig.js"
                }
            },
            "configurations": {
                "production": {
                    "customWebpackConfig": {
                        "path": "apps/myapp/webpackConfig.js"
                    },
                    "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                            "replace": "apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.ts",
                            "with": "apps/myapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    },
},
```

My .env file:

```
API_URL=https://someurl.com/
```

And my environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
};
```

Is there anything missing?